# GameServerQuery how to check if server is online & count online players?

Tags: php

I want to check if a quake3 game server is online or offline. If offline then echo 'Server is offline' if online then echo 'Server is online'.

I'm using [this](http://alexou.net/pub/?GameServerQuery/GameServerQuery.php) library:

As you see in the library there's already an ***isOnline*** function I think that's for server is online or no?! but I don't know how to output that.

Calling the game server data's:

```
<?php
include 'test/GameServerQuery.php';

$data = GameServerQuery::queryQuake3('1.1.1.1', 28960);

echo 'Hostname: ' . $data['sv_hostname'] . '<br />';
echo 'Players online: ' . $data['sv_maxclients'] . '<br />'; /// How can I count online players / maxclients? ex.: 0/20
echo 'Punkbuster: ' . $data['sv_punkbuster'] . '<br />';
?>
```

Here is relevant code from the library (in case the link should die or change):

```
public static function isOnline ($host, $port, $type)
{
    if ($type == 'minecraft') { // No need for the full ping
            return @fclose (@fsockopen ( $host , $port , $err , $errstr , 2 ));
    }

    if (method_exists('GameServerQuery', 'query'.$type)) {
        return self::{'query'.$type}($host , $port);
    }

    return @fclose (@fsockopen ( $host , $port , $err , $errstr , 2 ));
}

public static function queryQuake3($host, $port)
{
    $reponse = self::ping($host, $port, "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFgetstatus\x00");

    if ($reponse === false || substr($reponse, 0, 5) !== "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFs") {
        return false;
    }

    $reponse = substr($reponse, strpos($reponse, chr(10))+2);

    $info = array();
    $joueurs = substr($reponse, strpos($reponse,chr(10))+2);
    $reponse = substr($reponse, 0, strpos($reponse, chr(10)));

    while($reponse != ''){
        $info[self::getString($reponse, '\\')] = self::getString($reponse, '\\');
    }

    if (!empty($joueurs)) {
        $info['players'] = array();
        while ($joueurs != ''){
            $details = self::getString($joueurs, chr(10));
            $info['players'][] = array('frag' => self::getString($details, ' '),
                                                     'ping' => self::getString($details, ' '),
                                                     'name' => $details);
        }
    }
    return $info;
}

private static function ping($host, $port, $command)
{
    $socket = @stream_socket_client('udp://'.$host.':'.$port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
    if (!$errno && $socket) {
        stream_set_timeout($socket, 2);
        fwrite($socket, $command);
        $buffer = @fread($socket, 1500);
        fclose($socket);
        return $buffer;
    }
    return false;
}

private static function getString(&$chaine, $chr = "\x00")
{
    $data = strstr($chaine, $chr, true);
    $chaine = substr($chaine, strlen($data) + 1);

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a static function, just like the one you're already calling.  Something like this would do the job, I think:

```
$result = GameServerQuery::isOnline('1.1.1.1', 28960, "Quake3");
print_r($result);
```

That will show you what result you get back. I suspect it will be the same as the queryQuake3 function actually, because if you specify "Quake3" as the last parameter, the isOnline function will simply call the "queryQuake3" function and pass the result back directly.

So, the function should return either `false` if the server is offline or otherwise unresponsive, and either `true`, or a more complex dataset if it's online.

So in fact I think you could write:

```
$result = GameServerQuery::isOnline('1.1.1.1', 28960, "Quake3");
if ($result === false) {
  echo "Server is offline";
}
else {
  echo "Server is online";
}
```

Comment: Wow, really got the same results as the other calling. So I think I need to check if a server returns ping or not?! if the server have ping then online if not then offline or something like that.

Comment: It returns the same result because of this bit in the code of "isOnline": `if (method_exists('GameServerQuery', 'query'.$type)) {
            return self::{'query'.$type}($host , $port);
        }`

Comment: I think if you run it without the "type" argument you might get a simple true/false result (because it will fall into the last `return` line of the isOnline method and just make a standard socket connection, and close it again). So try `$result = GameServerQuery::isOnline('1.1.1.1', 28960);` and see what happens

Comment: But even if you do the original version, in the queryQuake3 function there is this bit: `if ($reponse === false || substr($reponse, 0, 5) !== "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFs") {
            return false;
        }` which means it will return `false` if it got no response from the server. So actually I think you can assume that if `$result === false` then the server is offline, and if not, then it's online.

Comment: if I try: $result = GameServerQuery::isOnline('1.1.1.1', 28960); then I got "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: that's an error in Chrome right? maybe you have some error in the PHP itself causing it to return an empty response. But actually I edited the answer above, to show a better way. Please see the update.

Comment: Yeah I saw it afterwards. And you're right. That's do what I want. Thank you so much!